# Javascript Check if Array is empty or undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that goes something like

```
//denominator is a passed argument. Integer

/*priceData will either be an empty array, or an array
that looks something like this
priceData = {
  'splitBy2' : [0.5, 0.5],
  'splitBy3' : [0.34, 0.33,0.33],
  'splitBy4': [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]
}
*/

//Returns list of values. Currency distribution. Eg if denominator = 3
//Then distribution will equal [0.34, 0.33,0.33]
distribution = distributionToArray(currency(totalPrice).distribute(denominator))

//This check doesn't work.
if(typeof (priceData['splitBy'+denominator]) !== 'undefined' && (priceData['splitBy'+denominator]).length == 0){

                priceData['splitBy'+denominator] = distribution;
    }
```

What I want to do is check if `priceData['splitBy'+denominator]` is empty. And if it isn't, create it.

So let

```
denominator=5
priceData = {
  'splitBy2' : [0.5, 0.5],
  'splitBy3' : [0.34, 0.33,0.33],
  'splitBy4': [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]
}
```

I want to check if priceData['splitBy5'] is set, and if it's not, run the rest of the function `priceData['splitBy5`] = distribution;` to create it. Even if priceData is empty.

Answer (score 3):

You've shown this code:

```
if(typeof (priceData['splitBy'+denominator]) !== 'undefined' && (priceData['splitBy'+denominator]).length == 0){
            priceData['splitBy'+denominator] = distribution;
}
```

and that should certainly work if the property A) Either doesn't exist or has the value `undefined`, or B) Has an array.

> What I want to do is check if `priceData['splitBy'+denominator]` is empty. And if it isn't, create it.

Your code should do that. But since an array (even an empty one) is a *truthy* value, you can do:

```
const key = "splitBy" + denominator;
if (!priceData[key] || priceData[key].length === 0) {
    priceData[key] = distribution;
}
```

`!priceData[key]` looks to see if the property doesn't exist (or has a falsy value; no array is falsy). `priceData[key].length === 0` checks to see if the array is empty. Since they're joined with `||` ("or"), if the first check is true the second isn't performed and so won't cause an error.

The two key (no pun!) changes there are:

1. Building the key once. This is purely so that we avoid typos like `splitby` instead of `splitBy` in one of the three places it would be used.
2. Using a falsy rather than `undefined` check.

But if you know the property won't be there, will have the value `undefined`, or will be an array, your code should work. All of the `'splitBy'+denominator` concatenations look like they're spelled the same, and the `typeof` check is correct (and doesn't misspell `undefined`, which is my particular bugaboo). You don't need any of those inner `()`, but they don't do any harm.

Comment: So your code works (yay!) but I did try basically exactly that before and it didn't work. The difference being you had key as a constant. Does it not work with dynamic keys?

Comment: @JoshDredge - You're right, looking more closely at the code in the question, that code should work just fine. The above works with dynamic keys. You could replace `key` with `"splitBy" + denominator` in all three places in the `if` and it would be just the same. Something else must have been going on. Is there some possibility that the property's value is some falsy value that isn't `undefined` (like `null`, `""`, `0`, `NaN`, or `false`)?

Comment: I really should have read the code in the question more closely before posting the answer, because I wouldn't have -- i'd've commented instead. Still, it looks like it's turned out useful for some reason, so...

Comment: Definitely useful, just don't know why. I was having trouble with dynamic jQuery selectors the other day  I never got working either so who knows!